# Extracting info from hdparm output

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

If you run `hdparm -I /dev/X` where `X` is your SSD device, it would print info (read-only operation) something similar to this

```
...
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 36401
        supported
    not enabled
        locked
    not frozen
        expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
...
```

So it should be easy to extract the `not` in front of `frozen` with

```
for d in $(ls /sys/block); do
    is_frozen=$(hdparm -I /dev/$d | awk '/frozen/ { print $1 }')
    echo $is_frozen
done
```

However it always return `frozen` as if `not` isn't there.

**Question**

Can someone explain how to extract the `not` from the `frozen` line?

Comment: Could you please post example for it(not working one)? output you posted that `awk` is working. Kindly do let us know.

Comment: The loop is suppose to print out `not` for each device, but nothing is printed. Somehow `not` is not parsed to `awk` from what I can tell.

Comment: perhaps not is not there, why don't you print the whole line to confirm?

Comment: That is what the first output shows in my OP. So I can see it is there.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting your script is correct. I tried it on my `/dev/sda` doing 
`sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | awk '/frozen/ { print $1 }'` and it worked and showed `not` .
The only possible explanation I could figure out is that the line with the word `frozen` contains only that word or that word is the first field of the line

Comment: FYI /dev/sr0 (DVD drive) sometimes does not show security section.

Comment: Pick a device and just do `hdparm -I /dev/the_device | cat -v`. Do you see any unexpected/control characters? Now do `hdparm -I /dev/the_device | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print NR, NF, i, "<" $i ">"}' | cat -v`. Does the line containing `frozen` look as expected? What about the lines immediately before/after it?

Comment: @EdMorton Ok, so now I see the problem. One of the devices gives lots of unexpected/control characters in the vendor ID and so it does something to the remaining output, so it can't be parsed. Is there a way to check for this, so I can ship those such devices?

Comment: Of course but without seeing what "it" is there's not much we can do to help you deal with it. [edit] your question to include details if you'd like help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system, /dev/sda is currently frozen and /dev/sdb is not frozen, as seen here:

```
# hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep frozen
        frozen
# hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep frozen
    not    frozen
```

Just add `$d` to your `echo` command to see the device and its correct corresponding value (I took the liberty of replacing the lengthy `awk` command with a much shorter `grep`):

```
# for d in $(ls /sys/block) ; do is_frozen=$(hdparm -I /dev/$d | grep frozen) ; echo $d $is_frozen ; done
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Invalid argument
loop0
...
sda frozen
sdb not frozen
```

If you'd like to cleanup the output, replace `ls` with `find`:

```
# for d in $(find /sys/block -name 'sd*' -exec basename {} \;) ; do is_frozen=$(hdparm -I /dev/$d | grep frozen) ; echo $d $is_frozen ; done
sda frozen
sdb not frozen
```

or have `ls` query `/dev/sd?` instead:

```
# for d in $(ls -1 /dev/sd?) ; do is_frozen=$(hdparm -I $d | grep frozen) ; echo $d $is_frozen ; done
/dev/sda frozen
/dev/sdb not frozen
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason may be that what you see on screen is not the result of awk, but of stderr. Here's what you can do to diagnose it :

1. Forego the for loop for now and test with one device, say sda.
2. Redirect the output to a file, e.g. $ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda > /tmp/tempfile
3. See if you still see the lines with 'frozen' no screen.